# Docker fails on npm install

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, installation

I'm new to Docker, and I've wanted try Dockerizing my node app.

I've tried following the directions on [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/), but I've been getting errors on `npm install`.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use the latest 'node' official version
FROM node:current

# Set working directory to /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json, package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy all remaining files from the current directory
  # Note: 'node_modules' will not be overwritten because of .dockerignore
  # See: .dockerignore for the full list of ignored files
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3031

# Start the container using the server:watch command
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here are the errors I've been receiving:

```
server$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.716MB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:current
 ---> b6f455933a97
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in fbc7ef703e8f
Removing intermediate container fbc7ef703e8f
 ---> 18682f683fa1
Step 3/8 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> 6f8ab073929f
Step 4/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 3105e1f65514
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @babel/parser@7.8.4 (sha512-0fKu/QqildpXmPVaRBoXOlyBb3MC+J0A66x97qEfLOMkn3u6nfY5esWogQwi/K0BjASYy4DbnsEWnpNL6qT5Mw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for source-map@0.5.7 (sha1-igOdLRAh0i0eoUyA2OpGi6LvP8w=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for source-map@0.5.7 (sha1-igOdLRAh0i0eoUyA2OpGi6LvP8w=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for tslint@6.0.0 (sha512-9nLya8GBtlFmmFMW7oXXwoXS1NkrccqTqAtwXzdPV9e2mqSEvCki6iHL/Fbzi5oqbugshzgGPk7KBb2qNP1DSA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for nodemailer@6.4.2 (sha512-g0n4nH1ONGvqYo1v72uSWvF/MRNnnq1LzmSzXb/6EPF3LFb51akOhgG3K2+aETAsJx90/Q5eFNTntu4vBCwyQQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @babel/parser@7.8.4 (sha512-0fKu/QqildpXmPVaRBoXOlyBb3MC+J0A66x97qEfLOMkn3u6nfY5esWogQwi/K0BjASYy4DbnsEWnpNL6qT5Mw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/@graphql-toolkit/schema-merging-eb6c200d/index.esm.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/@graphql-toolkit/core-0eb20c1b/index.esm.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-66ad0ba4/https.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/@graphql-toolkit/schema-merging-05667067/index.esm.js'
...
...
...
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/apollo-language-server-f6cf3e14/lib/engine/GraphQLDataSource.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/apollo-language-server-f6cf3e14/lib/graphqlTypes.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/serverless-146aad15/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-clojure-gradle/gradlew'
npm WARN server@0.0.2 No repository field.

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm WARN tarball tarball data for source-map@0.5.7 (sha1-igOdLRAh0i0eoUyA2OpGi6LvP8w=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-10T10_05_40_789Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Additional information:

- I am on Ubuntu 18.04
- npm install always works on my local machine (outside of docker). It only seems to break on Docker.
- Sometimes, the error ends with `npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY`.
- Sometimes, docker indefinitely hangs after the first few `npm WARN`.
- At the time of posting this question, I am using the latest LTS from nvm ls-remote (12.15.0). I have similarly tried downgrading to node 10 for both local and docker, with no success.

Please help.

**Edit:**
An example of the `npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY` error that I recieve.

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/node/node_modules/.staging/@storybook/core-bb4e5c86/dll/storybook_ui-manifest.json'
npm WARN server@0.0.2 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting validator@12.2.0:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting validator@12.2.0:
npm ERR! sha512-jJfE/DW6tIK1Ek8nCfNFqt8Wb3nzMoAbocBF6/Icgg1ZFSBpObdnwVY2jQj6qUqzhx5jc71fpvBWyLGO7Xl+nQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-jJfE/DW6tIK1Ek8nCfNFqt8Wb3nzMoAbocBF6/Icgg1ZFSBpObdnwVY2jQj6qUqzhx5jc71fpvBWyLGO7Xl+nQ== but got sha512-jbNiuTRS00nR58EcP7CCq2ld+M2yyKOEkKI0NwbUVCPecBmMiR8MFA7D7h/qKBzL+7DnmbZaNdPQr7DxIMGyoQ==. (69097 bytes)
```

**Edit#2**
An example of the output when I npm install after removing package-lock.json (hangs indefinitely at the end).

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.0.0: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-codegen@0.19.1: The 'apollo-codegen' command has been replaced with the more-powerful 'apollo' CLI. Switch to 'apollo' to ensure future updates and visit https://npm.im/apollo#code-generation for more information.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated @types/get-port@4.2.0: This is a stub types definition. get-port provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated superagent@3.8.3: Please note that v5.0.1+ of superagent removes User-Agent header by default, therefore you may need to add it yourself (e.g. GitHub blocks requests without a User-Agent header).  This notice will go away with v5.0.2+ once it is released.
npm WARN deprecated @types/vfile-message@2.0.0: This is a stub types definition. vfile-message provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN tarball tarball data for validator@^12.2.0 (sha512-jJfE/DW6tIK1Ek8nCfNFqt8Wb3nzMoAbocBF6/Icgg1ZFSBpObdnwVY2jQj6qUqzhx5jc71fpvBWyLGO7Xl+nQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@^3.7.5 (sha512-/P5lkRXkWHNAbcJIiHPfRoKqyd7bsyCma1hZNUGfn20qm64T6ZBlrzprymeu918H+mB/0rIg2gGK/BXkhhYgBw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for yargs@^15.0.0 (sha512-T39FNN1b6hCW4SOIk1XyTOWxtXdcen0t+XYrysQmChzSipvhBO8Bj0nK1ozAasdk24dNWuMZvr4k24nz+8HHLg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for web-resource-inliner@^4.3.3 (sha512-agVAgRhOOi4GVlvKK34oM23tDgH8390HfLnZY2HZl8OFBwKNvUJkH7t89AT2iluQP8w9VHAAKX6Z8EN7/9tqKA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for refractor@^2.4.1 (sha512-Xh9o7hQiQlDbxo5/XkOX6H+x/q8rmlmZKr97Ie1Q8ZM32IRRd3B/UxuA/yXDW79DBSXGWxm2yRTbcTVmAciJRw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
[            ......] | extract:@types/history: sill extract @types/history@* extracted to /home/node/node_modules/.staging/@types/history-677b6da5 (5080ms)
```

**Edit#3**
Pasting my package.json here (excluding scripts, description and author). There is no custom npm install or postinstall script.

```
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "main": "handler.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@koa/router": "^8.0.7",
        "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.40",
        "@types/base64-url": "^2.2.0",
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
        "@types/graphql-depth-limit": "^1.1.2",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.7",
        "@types/koa": "^2.11.0",
        "@types/koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
        "@types/koa-logger": "^3.1.1",
        "@types/koa-passport": "^4.0.2",
        "@types/koa__router": "^8.0.2",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
        "@types/mongodb": "^3.3.15",
        "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.0",
        "@types/node": "^13.7.0",
        "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
        "@types/object-hash": "^1.3.1",
        "@types/passport": "^1.0.2",
        "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
        "@types/redis": "^2.8.14",
        "@types/validator": "^12.0.1",
        "apollo-server-cache-redis": "^1.1.5",
        "apollo-server-koa": "^2.10.0",
        "base64-url": "^2.3.3",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "can-error": "^0.2.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "dataloader": "^2.0.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "graphql": "^14.6.0",
        "graphql-depth-limit": "^1.1.0",
        "graphql-middleware": "^4.0.2",
        "graphql-query-complexity": "^0.4.1",
        "graphql-rate-limit": "^2.0.1",
        "graphql-scalars": "^1.0.6",
        "graphql-shield": "^7.0.10",
        "graphql-tools": "^4.0.6",
        "http-status-codes": "^1.4.0",
        "iexcloud_api_wrapper": "^1.1.5",
        "jsonschema": "^1.2.5",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "juice": "^6.0.0",
        "koa": "^2.11.0",
        "koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.1",
        "koa-logger": "^3.2.1",
        "koa-passport": "^4.1.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "mongodb-memory-server": "^6.2.4",
        "mongoose": "^5.8.11",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.2",
        "object-hash": "^2.0.1",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-jss": "^10.0.4",
        "redis": "^2.8.0",
        "saslprep": "^1.0.3",
        "serverless-http": "^2.3.1",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
        "typescript": "^3.7.5",
        "validator": "^12.2.0",
        "winston": "^3.2.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
        "@geut/chan": "^2.1.1",
        "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.12.2",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.12.2",
        "@storybook/addon-docs": "^5.3.12",
        "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.12",
        "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^5.3.12",
        "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.3.12",
        "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.12",
        "@storybook/components": "^5.3.12",
        "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^1.5.2",
        "@storybook/react": "^5.3.12",
        "@storybook/theming": "^5.3.12",
        "@types/faker": "^4.1.9",
        "@types/jest": "^25.1.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.19.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^2.19.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.19.0",
        "audit-ci": "^2.4.2",
        "aws-lambda": "^1.0.5",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-require-context-hook": "^1.0.0",
        "customize-cra": "^0.9.1",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
        "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
        "eslint-plugin-mdx": "^1.6.8",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.1.7",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
        "faker": "^4.1.0",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "jest-transform-graphql": "^2.1.0",
        "node-loader": "^0.6.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "prettier": "^1.19.1",
        "react-scripts": "^3.3.1",
        "serverless": "^1.63.0",
        "serverless-dotenv-plugin": "^2.3.1",
        "serverless-offline": "^5.12.1",
        "serverless-webpack": "^5.2.0",
        "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "tsconfig-paths-jest": "0.0.1",
        "tslint": "^6.0.0",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
        "webpack-graphql-loader": "^1.0.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you need to give docker daemon more memory

Comment: @Eitank Is that the reason I am getting warnings from npm that tarball data is corrupted for several modules?

Comment: i would to just copy the package.json and run the container with a different cmd, then i would go into the container using `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/sh` and install it manually to see if there is an issue with a manual install.

Comment: @Eitank Running the command manually from within the container yielded the same result (but this time, it ended with  npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY (this is what usually happens instead of max call stack size exceeded).

Comment: which version of node.js do you run locally ????? @David Lee

Comment: @Eitank Thanks for the quick responses. When I try npm install after deleting package-lock.json, npm install appears to work briefly, before hitting similar issues with the tarball data corrupted, then hanging indefinitely. I'll post an additional edit to my post.

Comment: can you please tell me which is the version of node.js you use locally ? @David Lee

Comment: @Eitank Yes, sorry. I was in midst of editing my post with additional details. I've added to my details now that locally, I am currently using the latest LTS (12.15.0). I've also tried downgrading both on local and docker (node 10), but no success.

Comment: try making the node.js version on your local machine the same as the node.js base image that you use in the container.

Comment: @Eitank I believe I'm doing so already, no? The version I am running locally is 12.15.0, which is the same as node:current on docker hub. I've also matched versions when I've attempted downgrading to node:10 (as in the nodejs.org example).

Comment: try using the following tag `node:12.15.0-buster`

Comment: @Eitank After trying node:12.15.0-buster. And attempting both installing with and without package-lock.json, I am getting the same errors as I was before.

Comment: @Eitank Is there some kind of step I am missing, that is causing Docker not to connect to the npm registry? Or is connecting to it improperly?

Comment: can you post you package.json, try this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16861

Comment: i saw alot of answers regarding the package-lock.json making this happen

Comment: @Eitank I've posted my package.json to this post.

Comment: @Eitank I really don't know what to say about the package-lock.json. I've tried installing without it multiple times, and it appears to fail every time.

Comment: Again, npm install works perfectly fine on my machine. With and without package-lock.json. I am also running node 12.15.0 both on local and on Docker.

Comment: @Eitank Oh! I just succeeded in installing, but have no idea why. I've run npm cache clear --force && npm install --no-shrinkwrap --update-binary. And it seems to work. Should I revise my Dockerfile to include these somehow?

Comment: try to recreate it and then solve it again so that you know what actually solves it

Comment: @Eitank Ah unfortunately. I've discovered that this problem is still there. But it turns out, npm install works "eventually" when I retry the build enough times. Unfortunately, this won't work for me. I'm back to continuing research on my problem :(. Thanks for all your help though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used to get this error due to low or intermittent internet bandwidth.

Comment: Hmm... Well, my install appears to always work on my local machine, but not on Docker itself. Does that mean I have internet connectivity issues on Docker?

Comment: @DavidLee try building it on a remote server, that you know has a good connection for sure.

Comment: @Eitank Actually, I've discovered that `npm install` always succeeds (3 for 3) when I build with `--network=host`. Is there a way for me to force docker to build with setting network as host, without having to provide it every time?

Comment: @DavidLee, i managed to build your package.json's dependencies. i think its a network issue,

Comment: Yeah. It is definitely a network issue. I'm now figuring out how not to require network=host on my docker build command. But I'll mark this question as resolved for now. You guys are my heroes.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **package-lock.json**. If you have npm-shrinkwrap.json and node_modules then remove these as well and then finally remove the caching if any.

```
rm -rf package-lock.json npm-shrinkwrap.json node_modules  
npm cache clean --force
```

Now build a fresh docker container and the issue shold be resolved. Further add package-lock.json as a fresh file.

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```